# How align spaces in between using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am bit struggling to make spaces in between, I am using ml-auto. What I want to achieve is separate each control have its using spaces in between, "Core Status label" should be far each other and be on horizontal line between the two. This is what I have so far on the bootstrap;

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 ml-md-auto"></div>
    <label for="Core Status" class="col-form-label">Core Status</label>

</div>
<!--Viewing button/modules-->
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 ml-auto"></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModal">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        Module
    </button>
    <div class="col-xs-5 ml-2">

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4? There is no `col-xs-*` in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: @Simone, removed

Comment: you could try to add "d-flex justify-content-between" as a class for your row, that would apply the flexbox-row propertie justify-content: space between.  You can find the Bootstrap implementations fo Flex here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: it would be good if you add an example to view the issue with Codepen for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your controls to be in horizontal, within one row add controls and add **mr-auto**.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    
        <label for="Core Status" class="col mr-auto">Core Status</label>

        <div class="col">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModal">
                <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                    Module
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please find the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-field-7t9d0)